# Solve with lol code - How to bind data in nativescript Angular 6?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular6

[Solving Problem] i put new html for call data and success. lol

```
<StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
    <Label>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span text="Hi "></Span>
            <Span [text]="items[0].user"></Span>
            <Span text=" this is friendlist"></Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout>
    <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
            <GridLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]">
                <Label [text]="item.user"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Help me how to binding array data in nativescript angular 6 use httpclient service.

This is my user.component.html and the display only [object Object]

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name"
            class="list-group-item"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

When i change code to this code below, i can see the name of array one

```
<Label [text]="user[0].name"></Label>
```

This is my user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

userData(){
   let headers = this.createRequestHeader();
   return this.http.get(this.userUrl, { headers: headers });
}
```

This one my user component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '~/services/auth.service';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'user-selector',
    templateUrl : './user.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers   : [AuthService]
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

items: any;

id : number;
name : string;

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: RouterExtensions
) {
    this.items = [];
}

  ngOnInit():void{
     this.authService.userData()
       .subscribe(
       (result:any) => {
          this.items = result;
          console.log(this.items); // success on console but i dont know to binding data to html nativescript
       }
     )
  }
}
```

This result from console.log

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"john"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"natalia"
 }
]
```

Need result like this on my device:

```
no   : 1
name : John

no   :2
name : Natalia
```

Comment: `<Label [text]="user[0].name"></Label>` in this example you are using `user[0]` and u said it works but in the listview you are binding `items` property. There could be you are using wrong property...

Comment: i beginer in nativescript and angular... help me to sovling this sir

Comment: add all your component code

Comment: i have complete my user.component.ts sir

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be related to the common module not being imported - If you are using lazy loading make sure to add `NativeScriptCommonModule` to the related module imports. Also, import the `NativeScriptModule` in the main application module  - see details [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

For lazily loaded modules (like [this one](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/asteroids/asteroids.module.ts#L17))

```
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        // more imports foloow here
```

Comment: when i try to write code in console like this : console.log(this.authService.userData());

this output like this at terminal:
{"_isScalar": false,
"source": {
"_isScalar": false,
"source": {
"_isScalar": false,
"source": {
 "_isScalar": true,
"value": {
 "url": "http://api.example.com/user",
"body": null,
"reportProgress": false,
"withCredentials": false,
"responseType": "json",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
"normalizedNames": {},
 "lazyUpdate": null
 ...

Comment: Don't log the subscription but the result in the subscription (as done in your initial code snippet). What is the value of `console.log(this.items)` in the subscription

Comment: console.log(this.items) i got array user. but fail to binding. now when i create some html on listView <Label [text]="item[0].user"></Label>, data successful binding. now i use formatstring span to say hello user at top list view for success binding data, :D lol

Comment: Create a Playground with your codebase and I will take a look at it https://play.nativescript.org

Answer (score 1):

your data and service seems fine.

On template, you can try the following

```
<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
<ng-template let-item="item">
    <label [text]="item.id">:</label><Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name"
        class="list-group-item"></Label>
</ng-template>
```